# Where to get geometry 1.4.0?

Tags: ros, geometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I tried to clone geometry-experimental:
"hg clone https://ros-geometry-experimental.googlecode.com/hg/ geom"
and then switch to "geometry-1.4.0" branch:
"hg checkout geometry-1.4.0"
but it seems it does not exist.
I'd need eigen from that version which seems to be out of the unstable branch as well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9125/where-to-get-geometry-1.4.0-?/) by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1420 on 2011-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved - it turned out I was cloning the wrong repository.
It shall be https://ros-geometry.googlecode.com/hg (and not experimental).
D.

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2011-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0